# Accessing the value pointed by a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

**Edit: This question should be considered abandoned. I have flagged this question for deletion as i do not know how to even proceed any more at this point. I thank all of you for your willingness and taking the time out of your day to help me.**

I am reading and following the documentation at cplusplus on data structures. I have been trying to figure out why the compiler will not accept " *pfruit.weight; " on my own for hours. It am sure it is something simple that i am missing.

```
error C2228: left of '.weight' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'product *'
1>          did you intend to use '->' instead?
```

"The operand to the left of the period (.) is not a class, structure, or union."

**So how do i correctly access the value pointed by a pointer member?(Not access a reference)**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct product
{
int weight;
float price;
} ;

int main ()
{
product afruit;
product * pfruit;
pfruit = &afruit;

pfruit->weight;
    //Access a member of an object to which we have a reference
//equivalent to: (*pfruit).weight

*pfruit.weight; //<------ I am so sorry, i meant This is the problem, i am using a reworded line of code from an example and it isn't compiling and returning the error.
    //Access the value pointed by a pointer member called weight;
//equivalent to: *(pfruit.weight)

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try (*pfruit).weight. Error is 100% correct - pfruit is not a structure, it's a pointer to a structure. Please let me know it this answers your question and I'll convert my comment to a proper answer.

Comment: Your comment even says it 'equivalent to: (*pfruit).weight' not 'equivalent to: *pfruit.weight'

Comment: Since `pfruit` is a pointer, you can't use the non-pointer member access operator on it.

Comment: I don't understand. "Both expressions pmovie->title and (*pmovie).title are valid and both mean that we are evaluating the member title of the data structure pointed by a pointer called pmovie. It must be clearly differentiated from: *pmovie.title  which is equivalent to:
*(pmovie.title)"

Comment: @user2322359 Simply put, you can use "->" on a pointer and "." on a structure referenced by that pointer. Different notation, same result.

Comment: You are correct, but the `.` operator can't be used on a pointer to a structure. That's the error you get. Also, why would you want to dereference `pfruit->weight`? It's not a pointer so a derefernece of it, if the compiler would allow it, wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: I am extremely new to this so alot of what i do doesn't make sense lol. I have been teaching myself for not even a week yet.

Answer (score 4):

This code

```
struct product
{
int weight;
float price;
} ;

int main ()
{
    product * pfruit;

    *pfruit.weight;
```

is an *operator precedence* error. The rules of C++ are that `.` has higher precedence than `*`. `*pfruit.weight` would be correct if `pfruit` was a struct and `weight` was a pointer, but in your code it's the other way around, `pfruit` is the pointer and `weight` is just an int. So you need to add brackets to apply the operators the right way around

```
    (*pfruit).weight;
```

Comment: Where "pfruit->weight;" will access the **member** of an object to which we have a **reference**. AND where (*pfruit).weight; will access the **value** pointed by a pointer member. The thing that i am not getting though is that "(*pfruit).weight;" is said to be equivalent to "pfruit->weight;" which isn't accessing the value pointed. Or is the documentation wrong?

Comment: @user2322359 No you have that wrong. `pfruit->weight;` and `(*pfruit).weight;` are the same. They both access the value of weight using a pointer to the fruit structure. `*pfruit.weight;` is not legal with the declarations you have but it could be legal if you changed your declarations. There are no references, and no pointer members in your code. And it's not clear to me why you think this *'pfruit->weight; which isn't accessing the value pointed.'* when that is what it does.I think you must be thinking about this too hard, it's simpler than you think.

Comment: @user2322359 Member, value, pointer member? You are totally overthinking this. Just think of it like this: 1 + 2 * 3 is not the same as (1 + 2) * 3. The same goes for *pfruit.weight/*(pfruit.weight) and (*pfruit).weight

Comment: If you have a pointer to a struct use `->`. That's really all you need to know.

Comment: You say i don't have a reference but from the documentation. "The address that locates a variable within memory is what we call a reference to that variable. This reference to a variable can be obtained by preceding the identifier of a variable with an ampersand sign (&), known as reference operator" i.e. ted = &andy; So "pfruit = &afruit;" is a reference is it not?

Comment: It is late, i am tired and perhaps i need to look at this tomorrow with a fresh start. I am clearly not understanding this or not communicating properly.

Comment: @user2322359 Reference is a problematic word in C++. It has the usual meaning, but it also has a specific technical meaning in C++ (which doesn't apply here). I would avoid using the word unless you mean it in the technical sense.

Comment: *ampersand sign (&), known as reference operator* is not one I've heard before. I know that as the address-of operator. If you substitute address for reference in your documentation there would be far less confusion.

Comment: I do feel like we aren't on the same page. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ Top of the page.

Comment: I don't agree with that page, using reference like that is just bound to lead to confusion because most people use reference in C++ to mean something quite different. For instance wikipedia makes it quite clear that a reference is something differnet from a pointer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29

Comment: Care to explain? An address and a reference to my knowledge are pretty much the same thing.

Comment: OK, quite different was hyperbole, they are not quite different at all. I should have said quite *specific*. A reference is a C++ data type similar to a pointer, but the syntax and semantics are somewhat different. Really to use reference to mean anything other than the C++ reference type is hugely confusing.

Comment: I apologize and thank you for your willingness to help me but i meant that ( *pfruit.weight; ) is what i am having issue with. How do i access the value pointed by a pointer member called weight? (Ignore pfruit->weight; that is accessing a reference) If you could correct my code to where it accesses a value (like 10) pointed by a pointer member called weight that would certainly put me on the right tack to mentally grasping this.

Comment: `pfruit->weight;` accesses a value. That's all you need. I'm not sure where you've got this wrong idea about references from. And again there are no 'pointer members' in your code. And stop using the word reference! `pfruit->weight = 10; cout << pfruit->weight;` etc.

Comment: I think you should take you own advice and sleep on it. You've clearly think there is some complexity or subtlety here, but it's entirely in your own head. As I said before `pFruit->weight` is the right way.

Comment: You have used the term 'pointer member' several times, perhaps you could explain what you mean by that. It's not a term in common use and it's not obvious what you think you mean by it.

Comment: product * pfruit; -- *pfruit.title; (Title is a pointer member, since the pointer was declared under the data structure "product". I am sorry but i must say again, we are not on the same page.

Comment: OK that is **the very first time you have posted that code**, I think what you are looking for is *(pfruit->title).

Comment: John are you available for chat or something? It's hard to understand when the reply comes every 5 mins. That code has been there since the beginning.

Comment: There is no title in your code above, weight, price but not title. Is title the 'pointer member'?

Comment: Oh sorry i understand now, i mixed that up. What i meant to type was pfruit.weight

Comment: weight is not a pointer member. It just isn't. And my answer hasn't changed, use pfruit->weight. You still haven't explained why that isn't working for you.

Comment: Since the pointer was declared with the type struct or product it has the members weight and price. Pointer members.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wasting my time. Please explain why pfruit->weight isn't working as you expect. I'm not getting into arguments about semantics.

Comment: That doesn't work because i am trying to access the value pointed by, ( *pfruit.weight ) That doesn't compile. Not access the address of ( pfruit->weight; ). Again i apologize and thank you, it is 4 am here and i am not communicating effectively because i am tired.

Comment: Sorry, but this is waste of time, so this is my last post. Your question makes no sense. `pfruit->weight` is not an address, `*pfruit.weight` does not point to any value. You have a pointer `pfruit`, and you have a member `weight` which has a value. To get the value of the member you use `pfruit->weight` Anything else is your own invention. Goodbye and I hope it makes more sense in the morning.

Comment: You are being a bit rude, impatient and hostile. It also seems that you do not fully grasp the content enough to be able to help. Maybe you need to read this documentation as well lol.

Comment: Gosh. I only did my best, it was a little frustrating. I've been programming C++ for nearly 30 years now, so I do think I have a good understanding of the basics.

Comment: I do apologize john. I am frusturated at this problem, especially since it is 4 am. You are most likely right and i am overthinking this and/or i missed something but i have to go with the documentation in front of me as that is what my 4 measly days of experience is based entirely off of. I do thank you for help and taking time out of your day to do so but we appear to be too far off base from one another for this thread to be any benefit. I have flagged this question for deletion as i do not know how to even proceed any more at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following statement :

```
(*pfruit).weight;
```

Instead of :

```
*pfruit.weight;
```

which evaluates at compile-time to the following because of operator precedence :

```
*(pfruit.weight)
```

This is wrong because you are dereferencing a non-pointer value and trying
to dereference a pointer with the `.` operator instead of `->`.

**EDIT :**

Here's some piece of response and informations about pointers and to your question as I understood it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct product
{
  int   *weight;
  float price;
};

int             main()
{
  product       afruit;
  product       *pfruit;

  pfruit = &afruit;

  // Allocating 10 * sizeof(int) bytes of memory. ptr will now point to the first sizeof(int) bytes                                                                                                                                          
  // of the memory pointed by the weight pointer.                                                                                                                                                                                            
  pfruit->weight = new int[10];

  // The first sizeof(int) bytes of the memory pointed by ptr (equivalent to *ptr) equals now the value 4.                                                                                                                                   
  pfruit->weight[0] = 4;

  // The second sizeof(int) bytes of memory pointed by ptr (or (*ptr + 1)) equals now 42.                                                                                                                                                    
  pfruit->weight[1] = 42;

  // Dereferencing pfruit AND the pointer to the weight, thus returning the VALUE of the first sizeof(int) bytes of weight (4)                                                                                                               
  // instead of the value of the pointer to weight (0x8b4e008 for instance).                                                                                                                                                                
  int value = *(pfruit->weight);

  std::cout << "Value of pfruit->weight[0] = " << pfruit->weight[0] << std::endl
            << "Value of pfruit->weight[1] = " << pfruit->weight[1] << std::endl
            << "Value of *(pfruit->weight) = " << *(pfruit->weight) << std::endl
            << "Value of *(pfruit->weight + 1) = " << *(pfruit->weight + 1) << std::endl
            << "Value of ptr = " << std::hex << pfruit->weight << std::endl;

  // Prints :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  // Value of pfruit->weight[0] = 4                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  // Value of pfruit->weight[1] = 42                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  // Value of *(pfruit->weight) = 4                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  // Value of *(pfruit->weight + 1) = 42                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  // Value of ptr = 0x8b4e008                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  //                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  // Note that ptr[0] == *ptr and ptr[1] == (*ptr + 1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: I apologize and thank you for your willingness to help me but i meant that ( *pfruit.weight; ) is what i am having issue with. How do i access the value pointed by a pointer member called weight? (Ignore pfruit->weight;) If you could correct my code to where it accesses a value (like 10) pointed by a pointer member called weight that would certainly put me on the right tack to mentally grasping this.

Comment: I didn't fully understand but from what I did, it seems you are saying that `weight` is a member (a pointer actually) of `product`. I edited my answer as a response to your question

Comment: @HalimQarroum I hope you manage to get a better idea about what the OP is talking about than I did. But I really don't think he means 'pointer member' in the way you have shown. You've edited his structure declaration.

Comment: No, not quite. But the edit is useful material pertaining to the subject i am on and i have learned from your post. I am sorry i have failed so miserably at communicating and understanding the issues with you and everyone else. Thank you very much for your help and time and this question should be considered abandoned as i have given up on this particular question of mine for the time being.

Comment: Don't excuse yourself, your question was fine. Communication is sometimes difficult between people of different native language.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

once try this u may get it this can be written as pfruit->weight or (*pfruit).weight

```
   (*pfruit).weight;
```

Comment: I apologize and thank you for your willingness to help me but i meant that ( *pfruit.weight; ) is what i am having issue with. How do i access the value pointed by a pointer member called weight? (Ignore pfruit->weight;) If you could correct my code to where it accesses a value (like 10) pointed by a pointer member called weight that would certainly put me on the right tack to mentally grasping this.

Answer (score 0):

```
product afruit;
product * pfruit;
pfruit = &afruit;

pfruit->weight;
```

`pfruit` is a pointer and has the address of the struct `afruit`. 
We use `pfruit->weight` when we access struct members using a pointer .

When you use a struct name you use `.` operator.
Now, `pfruit` is the pointer . Therefore, the struct itself is `*pfruit`

```
*pfruit.weight;
```

This is interpreted as `*(pfruit.weight)`, because `.`has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `*`. and you can't use `.` operator with a pointer on LHS

You have to clearly show that you mean `(*pfruit).weight`

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but try this:

It sounds like you are expecting values like 'int weight' to be stored as pointers to data somewhere else in the same way that the product is being referred to via pfruit.  Some languages do do this, but in C++ simple data members like your weight and price are going to be stored actually in the product data structure.  So, if afruit happens to exist at address 1000 in memory, then pfruit will have the value 1000:

```
... 1000  1001  1002  1003  ...
  --+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
    | afruit... |     |     |
  --+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
      ^
      |
      pfruit = 1000
```

This means that your weight (int) and price (float) data members will be stored here, one after the other.  (and since an int and float are typically 32 bits in size, i.e. 4 bytes, the memory looks like this:

```
... 1000  1001  1002  1003  1004  1005  1006  1007  ...
  --+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
    | afruit...                                     |
    | <------ weight -----> | <------ price ------> |
  --+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
      ^
      |
      pfruit = 1000
```

Consequently, pfruit also happens to point at the weight data (because it's first in the structure), but the price data is 4 bytes further along.

So, when you say you want to get to the data 'pointed to by weight' it doesn't make sense because it actually turns out that you don't need to because when you access the weight member you are already referring to the weight value.  It's right there, in the memory occupied by afruit.

If you ARE trying to get a pointer TO the weight (or cost) data itself (instead of afruit, or actually from pfruit) you can do something like this:

```
int* pweight = &afruit.weight;  //from an actual product object
float* pcost = &pfruit->cost;   //via a pointer to a product object
```

There are now various ways to access the members of the product structure afruit:

```
afruit.weight = 20;     //directly access the structure member
pfruit->weight = 10;    //follow the structure pointer
*pweight = 15;      //derefernce the int pointer
```

I hope this helps someone, at least a little bit.

Sam